# trying to compare the Selected Value of an array of ComboBoxes

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox, compare

Trying to make an application in C# using Windows Forms in Visual Studio Version 15.  Id like to be able to check to make sure each selected item is different in each comboBox.  I've discovered that you can create an array of controls but the problem I'm having is in accessing the values in that array to check each one programmaticly

how could I use this array to check to see if all values are unique and return a simple bool?

```
Control[] statboxes = { comboBoxA, comboBoxB, comboBoxC, comboBoxD, comboBoxE, comboBoxF };
```

Comment: When you just started learning C#, I'd suggest that you learn WPF instead of WinForms (unless you'll have very good reasons, such as supporting legacy systems). It's way superior to WinForms, supporting MVVM quite easily, having a better layout system, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linq like this:

```
 var result = statboxes.Distinct().Count() == statboxes.Count();
```

Edit:

To check the unique selected item try this:

```
var result = statboxes.Select(s => ((ComboBox)s).SelectedItem).Distinct().Count() == statboxes.Select(s => ((ComboBox)s).SelectedItem).Count();
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I tried this already. This option doesn't seem interested in the Selected Item field.  at least that's my guess because it always returns  true.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I don't understand the problem. It works fine for me to compare an array with comboboxes like this. It returns true in this case:
ComboBox a = new ComboBox();
ComboBox b = new ComboBox();
Control[] stat = {a, b };
and false in this case:
Control[] stat2 = {a, b, a };

Comment: I think didn't understand you right. Check my edit, perhaps this is your solution.

Answer (score 0):

With `Combobox.selectedindex` you can select an item based on their index nr. And with `Combobox.selectedvalue`, you can select an item based on their name.

As for picking the unique values, you can use `Combobox.Distinct().Count`, which is explained in t2t's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `HashSet<T>.Add(value)` method with `Enumerable.All` extension method

```
// For example combobox values is of type int
var values = new HashSet<int>();
var isUnique = statboxes.All(combobox => values.Add((int)combobox.SelectedValue));
```

`HashSet<T>.Add` method will return `true` if given value was successfully added to the set and `false` if given value already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use ComboBox array instead of Control so you no need to cast it while doing your operation:

```
ComboBox[] statboxes = { comboBoxA, comboBoxB, comboBoxC, comboBoxD, 
comboBoxE, comboBoxF };
```

Then check if all of the comboboxes has unique selected value:

```
bool IsAllComboBoxesHasDistinctSelectedValue = statboxes.Select<ComboBox,string>((cb) =>cb.SelectedValue.ToString()).Distinct().Count() == statboxes.Count();
```